# C++ - Why is conv2 so slow in Armadillo?

Tags: c++, convolution, armadillo, openblas

I am using **conv2** function in armadillo with image size of 224x224 and mask size of 10x10. For a 3 channel image, I am doing something like:

```
arma::mat temp(215, 215, fill::zeros);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   temp += arma::mat(arma::conv2(image_channel, channel_mask)).submat(9, 9, 222, 222);
```

I want only **valid** convolution and hence I am using submat. This code is executed in a loop **32** times with different masks. For **32** iterations it takes 2.37 seconds which is way much slower than octave. Octave can execute the same code in 0.25 seconds.

Both octave and armadillo are set up to use OpenBLAS and I have defined appropriate flags in c++ file. (Eg. `ARMA_USE_BLAS` etc.). Can anybody please tell me what is the problem here.

Comment: Why are you tagging Octave at all in this question? Also, Octave does not use any BLAS to perform convolution.  If you do change to use Octave and have performance issues, consider installing the image package and use `fftconv2`.

Comment: I bet it would be faster if you did the `.submat` outside the loop.